# Fastest algorithm to compute (a^(2^N))%m?

Tags: algorithm, cryptography, modulo

There are well-known algorithms for cryptography to compute modular exponentiation (a^b)%c (like Right-to-left binary method here : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation).

But do algorithm exist to compute modular exponentiation of the form (a^(2^N))%m faster than with "classical" algorithms ?

Thank you very much !

Note :

1) m can be a very large prime ... or not (so no optimization depending on m)

2) N can be as large as 2^32-1 (N < 2^32)

Comment: Did you know that Ronald L. Rivest's [LCS35 Time Capsule Crypto-Puzzle](http://www.google.com/search?q=LCS35+Time+Capsule+Crypto-Puzzle) is based on this problem? And that this problem was chosen because it is an inherently serial computation. Although it uses `(2^(2^N))%m`.

Comment: Note that if you know the factorization of M, you can compute the answer faster than exponentiation.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If m is a prime, you can compute this much faster.

You start with computing of p = 2<sup>N</sup> % (m-1) with right-to-left binary method.

Then you use right-to-left binary method to compute a<sup>p</sup> % m, which is equal to the original expression because of [Fermat's little theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem).

---

If m is not prime, but small enough, so that it can be factored, you can compute Euler's totient function and use [Euler's Theorem](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/blue/Euler.shtml).

If no optimization depending on m is possible, probably the best you can do is using [Montgomery reduction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Montgomery_reduction).

Answer (score 3):

Also, as a generalization to Evgeny's answer: if you know the factorization of m: `m = p1 * p2 * ... * p{n}`, you can use [Euler's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem):

Calculate the totient `phi(m)= (p1-1)*(p2-1)*...*(p{n}-1)`.

Then you can compute `p  = 2^N % phi(m)` and find that `a^(2^N) % m = a^p % m`.

None of this uses the special form of `2^N`, however.

Answer (score 0):

Evgeny and Rasmus give great answers. To add to that, remember to use successive squaring for the powers. That is, write the exponent, say `E`, in base `2`:

```
E = b0*1 + b1*2 + ... + bk*2^k
```

where each `bi` is either `0` or `1` and `bk = 1` is the last nonzero bit. Then you can raise a number, say `N`, to the exponent `E` by

```
N^E (mod m) = n0^b0 * n1^b1 * ... * nk^bk (mod m)
```

where

```
n0 = N (mod m)
n1 = n0^2 (mod m)
n2 = n1^2 (mod m)
...
nk = n(k-1)^k (mod m)
```

For example, to compute `28^27 mod 76`, you have `N = 28`, `E = 27`, `m = 76`, and the computation is

```
27 =  1 +  2 +  8 + 16
 E = b0 + b1 + b3 + b4
```

and

```
n0 = 28 (mod 76) 
n1 = 28^2 (mod 76) = 24
n2 = 24^2 (mod 76) = 44
n3 = 44^2 (mod 76) = 36
n4 = 36^3 (mod 76) =  4
```

and finally

```
28^27 (mod 76) = 28 * 24 * 36 *  4 (mod 76) = 20
 N^ E (mod  m) = n0 * n1 * n3 * n4 (mod 76)
```